# No instance for (Num a) arising from a use of `sum' - Instance Num

Tags: haskell

this function works fine:

```
fromDigits :: [Int] -> Int
fromDigits n = sum (zipWith (\x y -> x*y) (n) (f n 0))
            where
                f :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
                f n x = if (x==length n) then []
                                         else (10^x):f n (x+1)
```

But if i want to change the type signature from the function, it does not work:

```
fromDigits :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
fromDigits n = sum (zipWith (\x y -> x*y) (n) (f n 0))
            where
                f :: (Num a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
                f n x = if (x==length n) then []
                                         else (10^x):f n (x+1)
```

Shouldn't this work too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, but not quite. The basic problem is that `length` has type `[a]->Int`. This will work:

```
fromDigits :: Num a => [a] -> a
fromDigits n = sum (zipWith (\x y -> x*y) (n) (f n 0))
  where
    f :: Num b => [b] -> Int -> [b]
    f n x = if (x==length n) then []
                             else (10^x):f n (x+1)
```

As Oleg Grenrus points out, one should always be careful to check if `Int` might overflow. It is in fact possible for this to happen if `Int` is 30, 31, or 32 bits, although it is relatively unlikely. However, if that is a concern, there is a way around it, using another function:

```
lengthIsExactly :: Integral n => n -> [a] -> Bool
lengthIsExactly = -- I'll let you figure this one out.
                  -- Remember: you can't use `length` here,
                  -- and `genericLength` is horribly inefficient,
                  -- and there's a completely different way.
```

You can make it easier to see how the types of `fromDigits` and `f` match up using a GHC extension. Enable the extension by adding

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

to the very top of your source file. Then you can write

```
fromDigits :: forall a . Num a => [a] -> a
fromDigits n = sum (zipWith (\x y -> x*y) (n) (f n 0))
  where
    f :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
    f n x = if (x==length n) then []
                             else (10^x):f n (x+1)
```

This way, it's clear that the list arguments all have the same type.

Comment: Also `(10 ^ x)` requires `Integral`, not only `Num`.

Comment: And `ScopedTypeVariables` aren't required, the `a`s can be different.

Comment: @OlegGrenrus, yes, I've completely rewritten it now, and actually made sure it works this time.

Comment: I forgot to state that in this case the 10^x will be using only 32 bit representation with no signal. But this is amazing, thank you a lot to all of you, i love to learn in this community :)

Comment: @dfeuer, You probably should point out that using `Int` is quite safe, as OP probably won't have lists with overflowing length. Yet it caught my attention.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using other functions that require even more of type a than just `Num a`

```
(^) requires "Integral a"
```

This works

```
fromDigits' :: (Num a, Integral a)=>[a] -> a
fromDigits' n = sum (zipWith (\x y -> x*y) (n) (f n 0))
        where
            f :: (Num a, Integral a)=>[a] -> a -> [a]
            f n x = if (x==fromIntegral (length n)) then []
                                     else (10^x):f n (x+1)
```

Comment: Doesn't the `Integral` constraint subsume the `Num` constraint?

Comment: `Eq` is a superclass of `Integral`: `class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where` and `class (Num a, Ord a) => Real a where`

Comment: @skills, `Num a` doesn't imply `Eq a`, but [`Integral a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) does, thru [`Real a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#t:Real)

Comment: You don't actually need to fuss with `Integral` at all. only the second argument of `f` needs to be `Integral`, and you can actually just make it `Int`. See my (revised) answer.